# TranslateService.use() works half of the time (ngx-translate)

Tags: angular, internationalization, observable, translation, ngx-translate

My application retrieves information about localization from backend via observable inside some localization module

```
constructor(translate: TranslateService){
  locale.subscribe(fetched_lang =>
    translate.use(fetched_lang)
  );
}
```

The problem is that language can be retrieved as **before** as well as **after** root component init.
In first case code works fine, but in second case `translate.use()` doesn't update translations but according to the network devtools fetches json with translations.

After that I tried manually switch on different language with simple

```
<button (click)="translate.use(other_lang)"></button>
```

And when I clicked the button firstly quickly showed up translations from `fetched_language`, and after that switched to `other_lang`.

The question is: how to change translations immediately after retrieving language?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is(probably) that NgZone does not detect async data flow. Thats why you need put your `translate.use()` inside `NgZone.run()`